# Can we recognise inaccessible url using apache CloseableHttpAsyncClient

Tags: httpclient

I am using **CloseableHttpAsyncClient** for downloading image with socketreadtimemout of 10 sec , connect timeout 5sec and doing a retry if it fails with sockettimeout and Timeout exception.

Now when the url is not accessible(404) then instead of resource not found exception it is failing with socket timeout and doing a retry again.So in my case for this invalid url also we are trying again and it adds up to the latency(~10+10=20 sec).

Below is the code snippet

```
    Future<HttpResponse> httpResponseFuture = asyncCloseableHttpClient.execute(httpUriRequest, null);
    try {
        return httpResponseFuture.get(10000, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS);
    } catch (ExecutionException e) {
        Throwable cause = e.getCause() != null ? e.getCause() : e;
       
        if (cause instanceof ConnectException) {
            
            throw new DownloadConnectionException("ConnectionException " + cause, DOWNLOAD_FAILED, cause);
        }
        if (cause instanceof SocketTimeoutException) {
            
            throw new DownloadTimeoutException(DOWNLOAD_TIMEOUT_EXCEPTION);
        }
        if (cause instanceof ConnectionClosedException) {
            
            throw new DownloadConnectionClosedException("ConnectionClosedException " + DOWNLOAD_FAILED, cause);
        }
        if(cause instanceof UnsupportedCharsetException) {
            
            throw new BadRequestException("Image download failed with UnsupportedCharsetException " + cause,
                INVALID_CONTENT_TYPE_EXCEPTION, cause);
        }
      
    } catch (TimeoutException e) {
       
        throw new DownloadTimeoutException(DOWNLOAD_TIMEOUT_EXCEPTION);
    }
```

This the config values for CloseableHttpAsyncClient

```
        RequestConfig config = RequestConfig.custom()
                .setSocketTimeout(10000)
                .setConnectTimeout(5000)
                .setRedirectsEnabled(true)
                .setMaxRedirects(3)
                .setStaleConnectionCheckEnabled(false) // never set this to true, 30 ms extra per request
                .setProxyPreferredAuthSchemes(Arrays.asList(AuthSchemes.BASIC))
                .build();
```

This is retry config
`RetryConfig.custom().maxAttempts(downloadAttempts).retryOnException(e -> ( e instanceof DownloadTimeoutException) ) .waitDuration(Duration.ofMillis(30)).build();`

To give more context why I am setting the socketreadtimemout of 10 sec because let's say for some bigger image download it may fail 1st time,so in that case retry is valid scenario but not in the resource not found case.

**Can we do anything to make resource not found/invalid url fail fast so that it wont fail with sockettimeout exception.**

Comment: Do you have any code to show how you are doing this currently?

Comment: Why you don't use HEAD request to check the header of url image, in case status 200, you can download it, other case, you can ignore and it save many times.

Comment: @msbit    added the code snippet